# run terminal after reboot and execute java jar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I need to reboot Linux, start terminal and execute java jar. My program works only when I start it using terminal and type:

```
java -jar /home/tom/program.jar
```

I tried to start it using `crontab -e` and `/etc/rc.local` adding this line:

```
java -jar /home/tom/program.jar
```

But it needs the active terminal for this program to work.

Do you have any idea, how Ubuntu can switch to terminal after reboot and execute my java jar?

Comment: Is it interactive program: do you input anything?

Comment: Are you sure, `java` is in your global PATH environment variable? Try to specify it absolut with its full path name.

Comment: Agree with @Olly ! E.g., `/usr/bin/java ...`

Comment: I tried in this way sudo /usr/bin/java -jar /home/tom/program.jar in /etc/rc.local This program needs to be run in the terminal because it uses firefox after executing

Comment: Define "terminal". Console terminal, or X terminal.